# Entity Framework Core - INSERT fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, exception, insert

The following function `AddCountries` deletes records (if they're not in use), then adds new or updates existing records. When called, it works fine. However, if it's called again (a new web request is sent to the server) it will fail with an exception

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Country' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Code:

```
public static int AddCountries(ApplicationDbContext db, Country[] CountryList)
{
    foreach (Country c in db.Country.ToList())
    {
        try
        {
            db.Remove(c);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            // country in use (foreign key)
            UndoChangesDbEntity(db, c);
        }
    }

    int cnt = 0;

    foreach (Country c in CountryList)
    {
        var c_db = db.Country.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == c.Code);

        if (c_db == null)
        {
            // adding new
            db.Country.Add(c);
        }
        else if (c_db.Name != c.Name)
        {
            // change of name
            c_db.Name = c.Name;
        }

        db.SaveChanges(); // *** EXCEPTION ***

        cnt++;
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

The helper function:

```
public static void UndoChangesDbEntity(DbContext context, object entity)
{
    var entry = context.Entry(entity);

    switch (entry.State)
    {
        case EntityState.Modified:
            entry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            break;

        case EntityState.Added:
            entry.State = EntityState.Detached;
            break;

        case EntityState.Deleted:
            entry.Reload();
            break;

        default: 
            break;
    }
}
```

Debug log when successful:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__c_Code_0='?' (Size = 2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT TOP(1) [x].[ID], [x].[Code], [x].[Name]
>   FROM [Country] AS [x]
>   WHERE [x].[Code] = @__c_Code_0
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 2), @p1='?' (Size = 100)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   INSERT INTO [Country] ([Code], [Name])
>   VALUES (@p0, @p1);
>   SELECT [ID]
>   FROM [Country]
>   WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = scope_identity();

Debug log when unsuccessful:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[@__c_Code_0='?' (Size = 2)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT TOP(1) [x].[ID], [x].[Code], [x].[Name]
>   FROM [Country] AS [x]
>   WHERE [x].[Code] = @__c_Code_0
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalCommandBuilderFactory:Information: Executed DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?', @p1='?' (Size = 2), @p2='?' (Size = 100)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SET NOCOUNT ON;
>   INSERT INTO [Country] ([ID], [Code], [Name])
>   VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);

You can see the problem - the `ID` is sent with the `INSERT` command, which causes it to fail (it's the autogenerated primary key). Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Its seen that your map is not updated . before doing any thing update your map model.

if you want to set it by code :
You can not insert a specific value into a column which the `IDENTITY_INSERT` property is Off.
You should set it on by this line code in sql :
`SET IDENTITY_INSERT TABLENAME ON`
and then Update your entity model map.
then run your application

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say. The data model is fine. It's pretty clear from the code that I'm not trying to set the ID field. The first call to the function works fine and the second one fails...?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem: what happened here is that SaveChanges() modified CountryList elements by setting it's ID's to those corresponding to the newly created rows in the database. In this case this is just an unwanted behavior of Entity Framework, so I have to recreate the CountryList for each call to the function, and that's it!